# Mypy, проверка импортируемых типов

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, static-analysis

Имеем 2 файла:

```py
# utils.py

class SomeClass:
    ...
```

```py
# main.py
from .utils import SomeClass


def some_func(argument: SomeClass):
    ...

some_func(123)
```

Mypy не будет ругаться на вызов функции `some_func` с аргументом `123`, так как, по видимому, из-за того что тип `SomeClass` импортирован, не знает как сравнить `int` и `SomeClass`.

При этом если `SomeClass` будет находится в том же файле, что и функция, Mypy проверку сделает и укажет на неверно переданный тип.

Умеет ли Mypy проверять импортируемые типы, или тут ничего не поделать?

**UPD:**

Mypy запускаю из корная проекта командой `mypy .`. Пробовал запускать с параметром `--strict`

Comment: @insolor Да, запускал с параметром --strict. Mypy запускаю командой "mypy ." из корня проекта

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Судя по наличию относительного импорта, у вас код в пакете. Если в этом случае проверять код как отдельные файлы, будет только на импорт ругаться:

```
main.py:1: error: Skipping analyzing ".utils": module is installed, but missing library stubs or py.typed marker [import-untyped]
```

Фактически ошибка означает, что mypy не может найти импортируемый модуль.

Чтобы mypy относительные импорты мог обрабатывать, нужно проверять код как пакет, запуская снаружи пакета с ключом `-p` (или `--package`):

```
❯ tree .
.
└── package
    ├── main.py
    └── utils.py

1 directory, 2 files
❯ mypy -p package
package/main.py:8: error: Argument 1 to "some_func" has incompatible type "int"; expected "SomeClass"  [arg-type]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 3 source files)
```

См. документацию [Running mypy and managing imports - Specifying code to be](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/running_mypy.html#specifying-code-to-be-checked), пункт 3.